# How to make VScode auto fix missing semicolons Apex?

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex, code-formatting, salesforce-development

Hey does anyone here know how to make VSCode auto fix missing semicolons instead of just show where it is missing?

I Started setting up Prettier and it will format apex code but not replace double quotes with single quotes nor insert missing semicolons.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I tried:

Prettier, Uncrustify and none of them worked for me.

```
if (o.Owner.Username == "maxi.musellus@energy.com"){
System.debug("why am I not bracced by singel quotes yet?")
}
```

this should be formatted to:

```
if (o.Owner.Username == 'maxi.musellus@energy.com'){
    System.debug('why am I not bracced by singel quotes yet?');
}
```

Id be greatful for any hint :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't formatting, it's syntax.

No Apex formatter will be able to handle these two items because code that requires those replacements is not syntactically valid Apex and cannot be parsed in order to determine how to format it.

Statements *must* end with a semicolon. Double quotes are not valid string delimiters in Apex - only single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, :) helpful

Do you know if there is a tool for syntactical correction?